# Launch simple php daemon on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, daemon

I want launch simple php daemon on Ubuntu without fork.

source f.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
file_put_contents('/var/www/3.txt',date("H:i:s", time()) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
while (true) {
    file_put_contents('/var/www/3.txt',date("H:i:s", time()) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    sleep(1);
}
```

launch:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www# ./f.php &
[3] 10323
```

On FreeBSD this work well on Ubuntu file 3.txt is not updating :(
permissions are ok (777)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check that the path you are pointing to for the binary file of PHP is correct, i mean PHP is really installed in /usr/bin/php, you can check that by using below command

```
which php
```

also you can try to run it manually instead of running it as an executable by below command

```
php -f f.php &
```

and also check if your php file is giving any errors in apache logs, you can find apache logs in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

and also make sure that `php5-cli` package is installed by executing following command

```
apt-get install php5-cli
```

**Update:**

according to http://www.freelance-it-consultant.com/blog/php-cli-script-running-background-ubuntu, there is some bug in ubuntu when php is run through CLI it expects some input from user, so can you try this method if that works for you?

```
php -q f.php < /dev/null &
```

Comment: all is installed, all work without & well and /var/log/apache2/error.log is useless because no apache starting )